# Querying in MongoDB with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a user interface from which I'm going to the name. And I have the data in MongoDB stored in the following manner:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6082bd42a5e8923c1823b43d"),
    "name" : "dfdsfd",
    "email" : "aggasf@jkdmf.com",
    "phno" : "7882360410",
    "password" : "kjhdfklklsad"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6086ec2dccc6ce106c649d29"),
     "name" : "nijsd",
     "email" : "agdfweth",
     "phno" : "3567325243",
     "password" : "cvbnxgb"
}
```

How can I get the "phno" from the given name; code written in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodejs mongo driver to query your database

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

// Database Name
const dbName = "myproject";
const client = new MongoClient(url);

client.connect(function (err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);
  let collection = db.collection("collectionName");
  let item = await collection.findOne({ name: "dfdsfd" });
  console.log(item)
  client.close();
});
```